# Banco de Dados Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, inner, sum

Como faço um select com `sum` e `inner join` para somar um valor x entre 3 tabelas. A `query` de retornar a menor numero de resultados possível.

```
create table credit_card (
        credit_card_id int primary key,
    nome varchar (30)
);

create table store (
    store_id int primary key,
    nome varchar (30)
);


create table sale (
    id serial primary key,
    data date,
    valor numeric,
    credit_card_fk int references credit_card (id),
    store_id_fk int references store (id)
);

     select * from store
     select * from credit_card
     select * from sale
     DROP TABLE CREDIT_CARD CASCADE
```

Isso nao sei como fazer:

```
   select  store.nome, store_id_fk, credit_card.nome, credit_card_fk, sale.valor, sale.data
   from sale 
   inner join store on (store.id= sale.store_id_fk)
   inner join credit_card on (credit_card.id= sale.credit_card_fk)
   order by store
```

Comment: Você terá que fazer os 3 selects, uni-los com `UNION` (pesquise o comando, é bem simples). Após isso, você fará um select nesse grupo que você criou, usando o `SUM()` para somar os valores e o `MIN()` para ver qual é o menor. Caso não conseguir, poste seu banco no http://sqlfiddle.com/ para que possamos simular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só uma tabela possui valor pra ser somado, então não tem essa questão de "Somar valor X entre 3 tabelas". Você deve fazer o inner join apenas para buscar os dados das tabelas `credit_card` e `store`, o valor você vai somar normalmente. A questão é: Por quais colunas você tem que agrupar?

Como você falou que deve retornar o menor número de resultados possível, acredito que seja agrupando pelo cartão e pela loja, mostrando o total vendido para cada um. Fiz um exemplo, Segue o código:

```
select
    t.nome as store_nome,
    c.nome as card_nome,
    sum(s.valor) as total_sale
from sale s
inner join store t on t.store_id = s.store_id_fk
inner join credit_card c on c.credit_card_id = s.credit_card_fk
group by t.nome, c.nome
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7fc5d/1

Leitura recomendada:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-agg.html